# How can I believe that Allah loves his people 70 times more than a mother if an infant dies off cancer?

Tags: allah

I am a Muslim but confused

How can I believe that Allah loves his people 70 times more than a mother if an infant dies off cancer?

Comment: What is the difference between an infant dying of cancer and an adult dying off cancer?

Answer (score -2):

I will only give you this line rest is on your interpretation :

If an infant dies he will directly go to jannah and will take her mother too jannah too

Comment: Why Allah made him go through the pain of a horrible disease like cancer in this world? Why did he even bring him to this world if this was his intension?

Comment: It was his test

Comment: For . Allah has said we will test every human being , for the rich the test is to give charity for the poor the test is to bear hunger , but allah will help them and guide them inshallah and allah knows the best

Comment: Test? Why test if Allah says he knows everything? He has written everything... why even he wants to test?